# Renaming a csv file placed in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks(Pyspark) to write a csv file inside Azure Blob Storage using:

```
file_location = "/mnt/ndemo/nsalman/curation/movies/"
df.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(file_location)
```

The file that is created is named as : *part-00000-tid-3921235530521294160-fb002878-253d-44f5-a773-7bda908c7178-13-1-c000.csv*

Now I am renaming it to "movies.csv" using this:

```
filePath = "/mnt/ndemo/nsalman/curation/movies/"
fs.rename(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(filePath+"part*"), spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(filePath+"movies.csv"))
```

After running it gives me this output:

[image]

Since I am new to Pyspark, I am not sure why is not my file being renamed? Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
old_file_name = "test1.csv"
new_file_name = "test2.csv"

dbutils.fs.mv(old_file_name,new_file_name)
```

working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command if you want to change the folder name ,

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/tmp/test", "dbfs:/tmp/test2", recurse=True)
```

if you want change the single file name ,

```
dbutils.fs.mv("dbfs:/mnt/all_tables.txt", "dbfs:/mnt/all_tables.txt_newname")
```

Example ,

[image]